# How does a hacker get access to my files if he got access to another user's files on a shared server?

Tags: webserver, server, ubuntu, breach

I host files on a shared server with Ubuntu 14.04. How does a hacker get access to my files if he got access to another user's files and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Your question is too general. What OS does the server use ?

Comment: @Overmind I updated the post

Comment: See this vulnerability list for 14.04: https://usn.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntu-14.04-lts/

Comment: You're basically asking us to make a forensic investigation without any access to your system. It's akin to telling a doctor "My wife is at home and she's sick. What medicine should I give her?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about **privileges**.

No matter what operating system you are refering to. The way to access a certain file path on a server is through privileges assigned to server users.

A user can share access privileges with other users to access certain files, but if an user doesn't have privileges to access that path, he can reach privileges by a technique called privilege scalation exploiting server's vulnerabilities, giving him or her access to routes that are not authorized for that user.

Comment: In short, if the admin of the main server does his job properly, I don't have to care about what other users on the same server do.

Comment: That is technically true.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options either the attacker managed to gain privilege access to the host of the service and can see everything or the files have the wrong security permissions.